# Object System and Potential Energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

I know that the object system doesn't incorporate PE due to gravity, but does the object system usually include PE due to springs or other factors, or is the object system exclude all PE and you would just have to figure out work done by all forces?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When calculating the energy of a system, you must take into account the kinetic energy and all potential energies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the term *object system.* Can you expand on this?

To calculate the work done on an object, you need to know the net force acting on it and its displacement, as vector quantities, while the force acts.

If the force is conservative, there will be a potential energy function associated with that force that you will need to know if you're concerned about calculating the total mechanical energy and/or showing that it is or is not conserved for a particular system.

Comment: In my AP Algebra based physics class we talked about the object system and the object-earth system. In the object earth system, Gravity is an internal force, so is expressed using PEg. The object system does not use PEg because it is an external force. Is the object system not a commonly used term?

Comment: It probably is a common term and I'm not aware of it. So we define *object system* to be a system containing only one object. All forces that act on the object are external by definition since it can't apply a force to itself. Whether any of the external forces are conservative will not matter if you are analyzing things strictly within the system, and you wouldn't need to know if they are conservative to calculate the work done by the net force acting on the object. You would just need to know that force and the object's displacement during the time that it acts.